# Firebase deploy gives "error loading firebase.json"

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I am working on an Angular 1.x project and I wanted to host it on Firebase, so I downloaded the CLI, logged in, and initiated the project.
After going through all the options where I selected the public folder, left it to install dependencies, created firebase.json..etc.. When I run `firebase deploy` I get the error below:

```
Error: There was an error loading firebase.json:

Unexpected token ' ' at 136:98
ild('profiles').child(auth.uid).child('person_type').val() >= 20002
                                                                    ^
```

Here's what I have in my firebase.json file:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "app",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried to look through my code for any references to the error it mentioned but I couldn't find anything. Is that possibly something in the firebase project itself that's causing this error?

Comment: It looks like you have a syntax error in your `database.rules.json` file at the line the error message indicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever it says there's an error in the `firebase.json` that includes all the files referenced into it.

In your case you have an error in your `database.rules.json` (which is referenced on your `firebase.json`), and i think it could be a validation you have at `line 136:98`.

I recommend you check the file and look for any syntax error (extra `,`, `;`, `{}`,`()`), in case there is no syntax errors, you need to check the logic of it. To check the logic you just need to copy and paste what you have in your `database.rules.json` file and paste it inside the firebase realtime database emulator in their webpage. Once you're in the emulator you'll see all the errors you might have.